# How do you find the periods with the highest or lowest overlap

Tags: mysql

I have a table called project_data that contains the items,start date,end date.

```
    items   startdate       enddate
      A    2018-02-13   2018-05-03
      B    2018-03-15   2018-04-03
      C    2018-04-23   2018-07-11
      D    2018-06-03   2018-08-03
      E    2018-08-24   2018-11-04
      F    2018-08-28   2018-10-22
```

My questions is that:
1.I want to merge the overlapping time periods and output them,Here's my expected result:

```
startdate       enddate
2018-02-13   2018-08-03
2018-08-24   2018-11-04
```

2.I wanted to find out when I was busiest (with the highest overlap) and what projects I was working on at the same time.Here's my expected result:

```
    startdate     enddate     item
   2018-03-15   2018-04-03    A,B
   2018-04-23   2018-05-03    A,C
   2018-06-03   2018-07-11    C,D
   2018-08-28   2018-10-22    E,F
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8+ or later?

Comment: I appreciate that these queries aren't completely straightforward. Nevertheless, we do like to see some attempt at solving them yourself.

Comment: yes,I use MYSQL 8.0